# ECS Fargate starts on a different IP on a new task - how to manage it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

ECS Fargate starts on a different IP on a new task - how to manage it?

What is the best practice to handle only 1 running task and connect it to a domain. I can't use the IP directly because changes on every task restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option, don't confused with the cheapest,  is to run tasks in an [ecs service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html), rather then individually. If you have service running, you can associate [network load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/load-balancer-types.html) (NLB) with it.

The reason for using NLB is that it provides **static public IPs** for you, unlike application load balancer (ALB).

But if your aim is just to have a stable endpoint to use for a domain, then **ALB should be enough**.

However, using ALB or NLB is not free.

As a side note, there is a proposal for adding Elastic IP support to Fargate:

- [[Fargate] [EIP support]: add Elastic IP support for Fargate #311](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/311)

So hopefully, providing static address for a task in Farget will be easier.

Comment: How can "But if your aim is just to have a stable endpoint to use for a domain, then ALB should be enough." be enough if ip changes? How to configure the DNS if ALB has no static ip? or is the same for as long as it started and doesn't change on each task restart?

Comment: @07mm8 Hi. if you use Route53 you create aliast record to ALB's DNS as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html). If not R53, you use CNAME record to the DNS.

Comment: thanks. after some research I gave up on fargate. Way too complicated for just an instance. I just created a simple EC2 instance and connected to the ECS. Now works :)

Comment: @07mm8 Glad it worked out :-)